React two select-lists and setState on other inputs
im having two select-list (where level2 select is getting sub values from level1 selected object) that causes mathematic calculations to disabled inputs that should show the result of the calculation. Those inputs should always show the latest version of calculations that is selected from the select-lists. It works almost, but it does always show the calculations one step behind.
i've tried to make a onChange-function that set the state of those disabled input's and it shows an old version of caluculation
I have also tried to use useEffect and flushSync to have to calculations to be always from those latest values that is show in level2 select-list with no luck
Is there a way to explict set the values of inputs, still having those inputs to be controlled state with setState-object or show other way around?
edit1, this is what i have been trying to do, but calcResults lags one step behind. Also i know that certain null-validations etc. are missing from this version. Also i've been trying to do this immediateCalcultaion-function to try onClick-event to have better 'react' to this problem with no luck
const TwoWaySelect = ({ operation, level1Objects }) => {
const [calculations, setCalculations] = useState(operation);

const [selectedLevel1, setSelectedLevel1] = useState();
const [selectedLevel1Id, setSelectedLevel1Id] = useState();
const [selectedLevel2, setSelectedLevel2] = useState();
const [selectedLevel2Id, setSelectedLevel2Id] = useState();

const handleLevel1Change = (e) => {
    setSelectedLevel1Id(e.target.value);
    setSelectedLevel1(level1Objects.filter(x => x.level1Id == e.target.value)[0]);
}
const handleLevel2Change = (e) => {
    setSelectedLevel2Id(selectedLevel1 && selectedLevel1.subObjects.filter(x => x.level2Id == e.target.value)[0].level2Id);
    setSelectedLevel2(selectedLevel1 && selectedLevel1.subObjects.filter(x => x.level2Id == e.target.value)[0]);
    calculations.calcResult = selectedLevel2.baseValue1 * selectedLevel2.baseValue2;
    setCalculations(calculations);
}
const immediateCalculation = (e) => {

}
return (
    <>
        <select
            name="level1"
            id="level1"
            value={selectedLevel1Id}
            onChange={handleLevel1Change}
            onClick={immediateCalculation}>
            {level1Objects && level1Objects.map((m, idx) =>
            (
                <option key={idx} value={m.level1Id}>{m.level1Name}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <select
            name="level2" id="level2"
            value={selectedLevel2Id}
            onChange={handleLevel2Change}>
            {selectedLevel1 && selectedLevel1.subObjects.map((m, idx) =>
            (
                <option key={idx} value={m.level2Id}>{m.level2Name}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <input
            type="number"
            name="calcResults"
            id="calcResults"
            disabled
            value={calculations.calcResult} />
    </>
)

}

Add some code so that we can analyze moreover you can check how to post questions.

I made the following changes to your component
const TwoWaySelect = ({operation={}, level1Objects }:any) => {
    const [selectedLevel1, setSelectedLevel1] = useState<any>(level1Objects[0]);
    const [selectedLevel2, setSelectedLevel2] = useState<any>(level1Objects[0].subObjects[0]);
    const [calculations, setCalculations] = useState(operation);

    const handleLevel1Change = (e:any) => {
        const selectedObj = level1Objects.find((x:any )=> x.level1Id == e.target.value);
        setSelectedLevel1(selectedObj);
        setSelectedLevel2(selectedObj.subObjects[0])
    }
    const handleLevel2Change = (e:any) => {
        const selectedObj = selectedLevel1 && selectedLevel1.subObjects.find((x:any) => x.level2Id == e.target.value);
        setSelectedLevel2(selectedObj);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(selectedLevel2){
            const calcResult = selectedLevel2.baseValue1 * selectedLevel2.baseValue2;
            setCalculations((prev:any) => ({...prev, calcResult}))
        }
    }, [selectedLevel2])

    return (
        <>
            <select
                name="level1"
                id="level1"
                value={selectedLevel1?.level1Id}
                onChange={handleLevel1Change}
            >
                {level1Objects.map((m: any, idx: number) => {
                    return <option key={idx} value={m.level1Id}>{m.level1Name}</option>
                })}

            </select>
            <select
                name="level2" id="level2"
                value={selectedLevel2?.level2Id}
                onChange={handleLevel2Change}>
                {selectedLevel1.subObjects.map((m: any, idx: number) => {
                    return <option key={idx} value={m.level2Id}>{m.level2Name}</option>
                })}

            </select>
            <input
                type="number"
                name="calcResults"
                id="calcResults"
                disabled
                value={calculations.calcResult}/>
        </>
    )
}

The above assumes that level1Objects is of the following format:
    const level1Objects = [{
        level1Id: 1,
        level1Name: "Level 1",
        subObjects: [
            {
                level2Id: 1,
                level2Name: "Level 2 Opt 1",
                baseValue1: 10,
                baseValue2: 20
            },
            {
                level2Id: 2,
                level2Name: "Level 2 Opt 2",
                baseValue1: 30,
                baseValue2: 40
            }
        ],
    },{
        level1Id: 2,
        level1Name: "Level 2",
        subObjects: [
            {
                level2Id: 3,
                level2Name: "Level 2 Opt 3",
                baseValue1: 50,
                baseValue2: 60
            },
            {
                level2Id: 4,
                level2Name: "Level 2 Opt 4",
                baseValue1: 70,
                baseValue2: 80
            }
        ]
    }]

The component now updates as soon as you make a selection thus the input value is shown correctly

And with those improvements, it does React! TY.
There must be some kind of magic in this line: setCalculations((prev:any) => ({...prev, calcResult}))
i think the const name in that improvement need to be same that there is in the object's properties.

That line is the same as setCalculations({...calculations, calcResult})

I think, what you were missing is         setSelectedLevel2(selectedObj.subObjects[0]) in handleLevel1Change and the useEffect :)
